# How to change the default size of a font file?

Tags: linux, fonts, kindle

Is it possible to change the default size of a font file.

I'm talking about `ttf` files. 
On my kindle paperwhite, I installed a couple of new fonts. Some of them works great, while some other appears too small, but enlarge it in the kindle menu results in a much larger font that is not good for read.

I'm wondering whether I could tweak the font file so that the default size will be bigger.

I work under the linux environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've googled a way using the free software fontforge. [Fontforge change font size](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=990853)

After installation, open the font file you want to change. 
The detailed steps are as follow:

1. go to: Edit>Select>SelectAll (all characters should be selected)
2. go to: Element>Tansformations>Transform
3. On the transform menu, I have chosen to increase by 20%...make sure all boxes below are checked.
4. Click ok
5. It should now render them 20% larger (or whatever you choose)
6. go to: File>Generate Fonts
   make sure you change filename to keep the original clean and de-select validate - otherwise you will get about 200 warnings
7. Click ok...there will be a couple of warnings that appear, but I have not found any visible font issues or errors-you can ignore them - hat is it. When you close Font Forge, it will ask you about saving changes...if you do, it creates another file type, but I have never paid attention to it.

Comment: Can confirm this is still valid for 2019. I'd like to add that Fontforge is free software.

Is there a difference between the transform resize and changing the EM value under 'element>font info>general'?